# How to find the number of ways of selecting three squares on a chessboard so that no two of the squares lie in same row, same column or same diagonal

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> Find the number of ways of selecting $3$ squares on a chessboard so that no two of the squares lie in the same row, same column or same diagonal.

What I have tried:

Square which not lie on same row or same columns as

$\displaystyle \binom{64}{1}\times \binom{49}{1}\times \binom{36}{1}=64\times 48\times 36=110592$

(In the above, I have selected $1$ square from $64$ and then selected $1$ square from $48$ and selected $1$ square from $36$)

Now selecting squares which not lie on same diagonals as

$\displaystyle \binom{8}{3}+2\bigg[\binom{7}{3}+\binom{6}{3}+\binom{5}{3}+\binom{4}{3}+\binom{3}{3}\bigg]=196$

(In above I have selecting $3$ square from $8$ main diagonal square and then $3$ from $7$ and then $3$ from $6$ and so on )

So required number of ways

$110592-196=110396$

But answer given is $18424$

I did not understand where I am wrong.

Comment: Try your same idea on some smaller boards, where you can also completely write on paper all the combos which work.

Comment: Do you mean that you wish to find the number of ways of selecting three squares on a chessboard so that no two of the squares lie in the same row, same column, or same diagonal?

Comment: Yes N.F. Taussing I am same thing

Comment: When you dealt with rows and columns, your goal seems to be selecting the squares so that no two of them lie in the same row or same column.  However, when you dealt with the diagonals, it seems like you were trying to eliminate those cases in which all three squares lie on the same diagonal.  Do you wish to eliminate those cases in which no two of the squares lie on the same diagonal?

Comment: Are these on the same diagonal?$$
\begin{matrix}
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  \triangle&  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  \triangle&  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  \triangle&  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\end{matrix}
$$

Comment: No these are not in same diagonal

Comment: You count (A1,B3,C5) and (A1,C5,B3) as 2 solutions. If you divide your number by 6, you are not so far from correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

First, $\binom{64}{3}=41664$, so your initial count is clearly incorrect -- you need to divide by $3!$ to account for the order of selection.

For the exclusion count there are two main diagonals, but you have counted only one along with parallels. If you subtract twice your exclusions from the corrected first count, you will get the given answer.

However, this only excludes cases in which all three squares are on the same diagonal, so the given answer is incorrect. A programmed enumeration finds $10320$ ways to select three squares with the given restrictions.

Comment: Thanks Daniel I have calculate but not getting.

Comment: @jacky $64*49*36=112896$ (You mistakenly used 48 instead of 49). Then $\frac{112896}{6}=18816$ and $18816-(196\times 2)=18424$

Comment: Thanks Daniel but I have seems that my actual answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

So we are are trying to place three indistinguishable queens on a chess board, so that no queen is attacking / protecting the other one. (A queen can move on same row, same column, and same of the one or two diagonals as where it is placed on.) This is only terminology, i find it simpler to make sentences in the sequel using this piece which looks like .

---

Here is a way to count the solutions that may be close to the one of the OP.
(The condition of not having two queens on same diagonal is unfortunately a different one, the posted question computes ways to put all three  on the same diagonal.)

Let the three points be $A_0=(i_0,j_0)$, $A_1=(i_1,j_1)$, and $A_2=(i_2,j_2)$.
The indices are running in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}^{\times 2}$, but we may also use the chess notation, indices being in
$\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h\}\times\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$.

---

Consider the following sets:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Bbb A^+ &= \{\ A=(A_0, A_1, A_2)\ : \ A_0, A_1, A_2\text{ in different rows and columns }\}\ ,\\
\Bbb A &= \{\ A=(A_0, A_1, A_2)\in\Bbb A^+\ : \ A_0, A_1, A_2\text{ all three on different diagonals }\}\ ,\\
\Bbb A_{01} &= \{\ A=(A_0, A_1, A_2)\in\Bbb A^+\ : \ A_0, A_1\text{ in same diagonal }\}\ ,\\
\Bbb A_{02} &= \{\ A=(A_0, A_1, A_2)\in\Bbb A^+\ : \ A_0, A_2\text{ in same diagonal }\}\ ,\\
\Bbb A_{12} &= \{\ A=(A_0, A_1, A_2)\in\Bbb A^+\ : \ A_1, A_2\text{ in same diagonal }\}\ ,\\
\Bbb A_{01, 02} &= A_{01}\cap A_{02}\ ,\\
\Bbb A_{01, 12} &= A_{01}\cap A_{12}\ ,\\
\Bbb A_{02, 12} &= A_{02}\cap A_{12}\ ,\\
\Bbb A_{012} &= A_{01}\cap A_{02}\cap A_{12}=
\{\ A=(A_0, A_1, A_2)\in\Bbb A^+\ : \ A_0,A_1, A_2\text{ in one=same diagonal }\}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The number of elements of a set $S$ will be denoted by $N(S)$ below. We need
$N(\Bbb A)$ divided by six, since $N(\Bbb A)$ is counting tuples, configurations of three ordered queens.
There is the following relation:
$$
\tag{$*$}
N(\Bbb A)
=
N(\Bbb A^+)
-
N(\Bbb A_{01}\cup\Bbb A_{02}\cup\Bbb A_{12})
\ , 
$$
and for the last number we use the inclusion exclusion principle.
Let us compute some cardinalities:
$$
\begin{aligned}
N(\Bbb A^+) &= 8^2\cdot7^2\cdot 6^2=112896\ ,\\
N(\Bbb A_{01}) &= 
2\cdot 2!
\left(
\binom 82
+ 2\binom 72
+ 2\binom 62
+ 2\binom 52
+ 2\binom 42
+ 2\binom 32
+ 2\binom 22
\right)\cdot 6^2
\\
&=2\cdot 2\cdot 140\cdot 6^2= 20160
\ ,
\\
% N(\Bbb A_{02}) &= 20160\ ,\\
% N(\Bbb A_{12}) &= 20160\ ,\\
N(\Bbb A_{012}) &= 
2\cdot 3!
\left(
\binom 83
+ 2\binom 73
+ 2\binom 63
+ 2\binom 53
+ 2\binom 43
+ 2\binom 33
\right)\cdot 6^2
\\
&=2\cdot 6\cdot 196=2352\ .
\\[3mm]
N(\Bbb A_{01,02}-\Bbb A_{012}) &= 
2!\cdot 4\Bigg(
\underbrace{0}_{A_0=a1} +
\underbrace{(1\cdot 6-1)}_{A_0=b1} +
\underbrace{(2\cdot 5-2)}_{A_0=c1} +
\underbrace{(3\cdot 4-3)}_{A_0=d1} 
\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad +
\underbrace{(1\cdot 6-1)}_{A_0=a2} +
\underbrace{(2\cdot 7-4)}_{A_0=b2} +
\underbrace{(3\cdot 6-5)}_{A_0=c2} +
\underbrace{(4\cdot 5-6)}_{A_0=d2} 
\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad +
\underbrace{(2\cdot 5-2)}_{A_0=a3} +
\underbrace{(3\cdot 6-5)}_{A_0=b3} +
\underbrace{(4\cdot 7-8)}_{A_0=c3} +
\underbrace{(5\cdot 6-9)}_{A_0=d3} 
\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad +
\underbrace{(3\cdot 4-3)}_{A_0=a4} +
\underbrace{(4\cdot 5-6)}_{A_0=b4} +
\underbrace{(5\cdot 6-9)}_{A_0=c4} +
\underbrace{(6\cdot 7-12)}_{A_0=d4} 
\Bigg)
\\
&=8\Bigg(5+8+9+5+10+13+14+8+13+20+21+9+14+21+30
\Bigg)
\\
&=8\cdot200=1600\ ,\\
\\
N(\Bbb A_{01,02}) &= 
2352+1600=3952\ ,\\
N(\Bbb A^+-\Bbb A)
&=
N(\Bbb A_{01}\cup\Bbb A_{02}\cup\Bbb A_{12})
\\
&=3N(\Bbb A_{01})
-3N(\Bbb A_{01}\cap \Bbb A_{02})
+N(\Bbb A_{01}\cap \Bbb A_{02}\cap \Bbb A_{12})
\\
&=3\cdot 20160-3\cdot 3952 + 2352=50976\ ,\\
N(\Bbb A)&=112896 - 50976=61920
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So the wanted answer is:
$$
\color{blue}{
\frac 1{3!}
N(\Bbb A)
=\frac 16\cdot 61920=10320\ .
}
$$

---

Sage code to check the result:

```
R = [1..8]
count = 0
for i0, j0, i1, j1, i2, j2 in cartesian_product(6*[R]):
    if (i0, j0) < (i1, j1) and (i1, j1) < (i2, j2):
        if ( prod([i0 - i1, i0 - i2, i1 - i2]) and
             prod([j0 - j1, j0 - j2, j1 - j2]) and
             (j0 - j1)/(i0 - i1) not in (-1, 1) and
             (j0 - j2)/(i0 - i2) not in (-1, 1) and
             (j1 - j2)/(i1 - i2) not in (-1, 1) ):
            count += 1
print(count)
```

It delivers `10320`.

---

A note on the above computation of $N(\Bbb A_{01,02}-\Bbb A_{012})$.
It corresponds to configurations $A=(A_0,A_1,A_2)$ of three  such that both  two diagonals through $A_0$ (well, one may degenerate, forget this case) contain each the one or the other queen. Because of the symmetry of the board, it is enough to look for the cases when $A_0$ is in the square $\{1,2,3,4\}^{\times 2}$, in chess it has the corners a1, d1, a4, d4.
Of course we can restrict to the cases below and on the diagonal a1 - d4.
Let us pick some squares.
For a1 one diagonal degenerates. For b1 we have two diagonals, one has length $2$, the other one has length $7$, so there are $1\cdot 6$ ways to put one  on the first diagonal, the second  on the other. However, some configurations are not allowed, we subtract the one configuration $A=(b1,a2,b3)$. It is always a good idea to look at the elements on the "shorter" diagonal when establishing the cases to be subtracted. In the same manner we proceed also with the other squares. For instance, for d3 we have a short diagonal (a6, b5, c4, d3, e2, f1) and a long diagonal (b1, c2, d3, e4, f5, g6, h7) through it. There are $5\times 6$ cases to pick two  independently on them. However, the choice a6 for one  eliminates the g6 case from the other one. One case. The case b5 eliminates b1, f5 from the second diagonal. Two cases. So we subtract from $5\cdot 6$ some pieces, explicitly we get the correct number
$5\cdot 6-1_{a6}-2_{b5}-2_{c4}-2_{e2}-2_{f1}=5\cdot 6-9$. This is the corresponding counter for the field d3.